# Parse.com Http request body parameter differs using ' or "

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, httprequest, quotes, double-quotes

I want to send body's key values as variables but as in the code it doesn't work. What's exactly the difference and how can I solve this by using variables. I believe the problem is caused by JS dictionary's base characteristics but couldn't find anything related.

```
var withq = 'entry_xxx';
var withdoubleq = "entry_xxx";

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: doc_url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        'entry_xxx' : object, // works
  },
})

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: doc_url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        "entry_xxx" : object, // doesn't work
  },
})

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: doc_url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        withq : object,       // doesn't work 
  },
})

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: doc_url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        withdoubleq : object  // doesn't work
  },
})
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual code that you use. All of the keys that you show are perfectly valid in a Javascript object literal, and specifying the key in different ways doesn't change how the property is created.

Comment: edited you can checkout

Comment: There is no reason that `{ 'entry_xxx' : object }` would give a different result than `{ "entry_xxx" : object }`, they are perfectly equivalent. There has to be some other difference in the code. Regarding the others, `{ withq: object }` is the same as `{ 'withq': object }`, i.e. the identifier for the key doesn't need quotes, and you can't use a variable for the key in an object literal. Also, you have trailing commas in the objects (between the last item and `}`), that doesn't work in some browsers.

Comment: thanks I'll check out again. Since its a cloud code (not a browser) I didn't cared about the commas but I guess it's not wrong to put it in cloud code?